# Google places / maps API get subway_station city's list

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, geocoding, google-places

I need to get the subway/traffic points list for the country/city.
need to get the `lat`, `lng`, `name` as minimum requirement.

Is it possible through any google maps-related API? 
If yes, how?

P.S.
Preferably using `JAVA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Google Places API with this call:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

You can use Nearby Search Requests search type.

The Google documentation states:

> radius — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place
>   results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that radius
>   must not be included if rankby=distance (described under Optional
>   parameters below) is specified.

To filter for subway stations you will have to use the subway_station place type as input parameter ( https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types ).

Having in mind the maximum 50km radius constraint, to search for all subway stations in a larger area (country / big city) you can divide that area in ~ 35.3 km squares (the biggest square fitting the circle = 50km * sqrt(2) ).

[This article](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates) describes in some detail how you can sequentially get the bounding points of the rectangles in such a grid.

Google Places has a Java client you can use:
https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library